# how to improve performance to run faster (python)

Tags: performance, python-3.x, recursion

Right now, my program takes more than 10mins LOL try to display all the possible words (if those words are in the file) that can be created from the given letters. In that file, it has more than 4000+ words
How to make my program run faster by using recursion, and not using any libraries because i'm new to it.

```
if user input letters: b d o s y
```

then it will look up all the possible words in that file to create:

```
b
d
boy
boys
by
```

the code:

```
words = set()

def found(word, file):

##    Reads through file and tries
##    to match given word in a line.

    with open(file, 'r') as rf:
        for line in rf.readlines():
            if line.strip() == word:
                return True
        return False


def scramble(r_letters, s_letters):   
##    Output every possible combination of a word.
##    Each recursive call moves a letter from
##    r_letters (remaining letters) to
##    s_letters (scrambled letters)

    if s_letters:
        words.add(s_letters)
    for i in range(len(r_letters)):
        scramble(r_letters[:i] + r_letters[i+1:], s_letters + r_letters[i])

thesarus = input("Enter the name of the file containing all of the words: ")
letters  = input("Please enter your letters separated by a space: ")
word = ''.join(letters.split(' '))
scramble(word, '')
ll = list(words)
ll.sort()
for word in ll:
    if found(word, thesarus):
        print(word)
```

Comment: Using some low level language for performance critic passages is more than legal, though tougher to produce and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

You program runs slow because your algorithm is inefficient.
Since you require in the question to use recursion (to generate all the possible combinations), you could improve at least in how you search in the file.

Your code open the file and search a single word reading it for every word. This is extremely inefficient.

First solution it comes into my mind is to read the file once and save each word in a `set()`

```
words_set = {line.strip() for line in open('somefile')}
```

or also (less concise)

```
words_set = set()
with open('somefile') as fp:
    for line in fp:
        words_set.add(line.strip())
```

Then, you just do

```
if word in words_set:
     print(word)
```

I think there could be more efficient ways to do the whole program, but they don't require recursion.

## Update

For the sake of discussion, I think it may be useful to also provide an algorithm which is better.

Your code generates all possible combinations, even if those are not likely to be part of a dictionary, in addition to the inefficient search in the file for each word.

A better solution involves storing the words in a more efficient way, such that it is much easier to tell if a particular combination exists or not. For example, you don't want to visit (in the file) all the words composed by characters not present in the list provided by the user.

There is a data structure which I believe to be quite effective for this kind of problems: the [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) (or prefix tree). This data structure can be used to store all the thesaurus file, in place of the set that I suggested above.

Then, instead of generating all the possible combinations of letters, you just visit the tree with all the possible letters to find all the possible *valid* words.

So, for example, if your user enters `h o m e x` and you have no word starting with `x` in your thesaurus, you will not generate all the permutations starting with `x`, such as xe, xo, xh, xm, etc, saving a large amount of computations.